# How do you install a .sfw firmware file?

Tags: firmware

I'm trying to update firmware for a USB lidar. The firmware link (http://scanse.io/downloads) downloads a .sfw file, but I have no idea what to do with it.

Comment: Did you see this page? [Upgrading Firmware](https://support.scanse.io/hc/en-us/articles/224557908-Upgrading-Firmware)

Comment: I guess I didn't dig deep enough, but thank you to both of you guys! Guess this is off topic for the site though, but I didn't realize at the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [visualizer .deb](https://s3.amazonaws.com/scanse/Visualizer/v0.12.1/sweepvisualizer_0.12.1_amd64.deb) file from your link.

According to the manual,

> It contains a programming tool for updating Sweep’s firmware. A full
>   tutorial for using the visualizer can be found in software support
>   section at support.scanse.io.